# What the meaning of `../` in Linux?

Tags: shell, syntax

I'm doing some exercises on memcached and Ubuntu. I got to some step where Isee this:

`user1@user1-VirtualBox:~/temp$ cat ../synchro.sh`

The content of this file is:

```
#!/bin/bash
server="--servers localhost"
key="test30"
getkey="memccat $server $key"
$getkey
if [ $? -ne 0]
 then
  echo "ERROR - cache miss"
  /usr/bin/memccp $server --expire=30 $key && $getkey
 fi
```

I've created a file in the temp folder, but when I run again the command I get the same error:

```
cat: ../synchro.sh: No such file or directory
```

I've googled using `../`, `cat ../`, etc., but I don't see any result that explains the meaning of `../`.

Comment: up to the parent folder from the one you're in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a "Ubuntu" thing but a [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) file systems thing.

The `../` indicate the path of the parent directory.

Example:

```
cd /Home/directory
cd ../
```

After typing those two command I will be in `/Home`.

You might also have seen `./` which is the curent directory.